# Error in if (nval != nrow(par0$Rho)) stop(paste("Row dimension of \"Rho\" not equal to\n", : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I am using the hmm.discnp library and combining it with Hmm library in R. I am trying to incorporate my data into HMM and it is giving me above error. Here is the code:

```
#Reading the csv file
corpus1<-read.csv("C:/Users/harspath/Downloads/Personal/RData.csv", header = TRUE)
good_data<- as.list(corpus1)
#Defining Libraries 
library (HMM)
require(hmm.discnp)
#Defining states i.e. End State and symbols i.e. the observations
states=c("Buying", "Not Buying")

symbols=c("ID", "Device ID","DeviceOSVector","MobileBrandVector","BrowserVector","SearchValueVector","TimeOnPage","NoOfCicks","NoOfScrolls","PageLoadTime","TaskComplete")

hmm1 <- initHMM ( states, symbols,startProbs=NULL,transProbs=NULL, emissionProbs=NULL)

tpm<-hmm1$transProbs

rho<-hmm1$emissionProbs

my_hmm = hmm(good_data,par0 = list(tpm,rho),stationary=FALSE)

# transition probability matrix
my_hmm$tpm
# output probabilities
my_hmm$Rho
# initial probabilities (don't know/know)
my_hmm$ispd
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
my_hmm = hmm(good_data,par0 = list(tpm,Rho = rho),stationary=FALSE)
```

OR:

```
Rho<-hmm1$emissionProbs
my_hmm = hmm(good_data,par0 = list(tpm,Rho),stationary=FALSE)
```

The reasoning here is that the `par0` argument expects a named list. The names should be `tpm` and `Rho` (upper case first letter). However, you have written `rho` (lower case). From `?hmm`:

> par0
>
> An optional (named) list of starting values for the parameters of the model, with components tpm (transition probability matrix) and Rho. The matrix Rho specifies the probability that the observations take on each value in yval, given the state of the hidden Markov chain. The columns of Rho correspond to states, the rows to the values of yval.

In the error, you can see that `hmm` has the following code:

```
if (nval != nrow(par0$Rho)) *something*
```

So, it tries to look in `par0$Rho`. Since you don't have that one, you get the error `argument is of length zero`.

Comment: I'll see tht. Can you tell me how to convert data to observation sequence in R?

Comment: That's a very broad question. There are many packages to do that, including the ones that you have tried. I am not familiar with any of the packages, but it seems that there is some stuff available if you google for `tutorial hmm r`.